# How to know which subLayer to remove?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerlayer

I have the bellow line of code which is meant to prevent a problem where a sublayer is displayed over another posts content. The method in which this line is excited is called at the time of the user exiting a post.

```
newBaseP3FolderLayer.layer.sublayers?.remove(at: 1)
```

But now, I think as a result of this code, there are instances where another video will all of a sudden cover all other images.

I noticed that this only happens when the number of subLayers is 14. (This also may be true for numbers above this) while printing the number of sublayers when leaving a post I noticed that the code worked fine (for vals like 10 or 11 and 12) until the number of subviews went to 14.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide more code, screenshots please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be better approach

```
for sublayer in sublayers {
    if sublayer.name == "yourLayerName" {
        sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the `reference` to the `layer` you want to remove while creating it and use that `reference` to remove the `layer` from its `superLayer`, i.e.

```
var yourLayer: CALayer?

view.layer.sublayers?.forEach({ (layer) in
    if layer == yourLayer {
        yourLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use layer names, try logging this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.playerLayer.player.currentItem.asset);
```

You will see the following:

> AVURLAsset: 0x60000063bac0, URL = file:///Temp/Loops/088_JB_HD.mov

You can then identify the actual name and URL of your asset.